# Setting a locale for textviews in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, locale

I want to set locale for a single text view . Which means only that textview will be shown in another language (in my example french) but unfortunately it is not working. While I do not get an error, nothing happens.

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
 maintext.setTextLocale(locale);
tried updating confguirations , same thing . Nothing changes .

 Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
    getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
maintext.setTextLocale(locale);
```

I tried doing that in normal activities and it worked perfectly fine .

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am stuck the same way you were. This method doesn't work on fragments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format()` with `Locale.FRENCH` to localize the text of that TextView.

**example**

```java
String txtFrench = String.format(Locale.FRENCH, "%s", item.getFrenchName());
mFrenchTextView.setText(txtFrench);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text locale via setTextLocale only specifies the type of font to use to render the text. The locale is applied directly to the underlying Paint object used to render the font on the screen.
Here's the documentation for the call: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextLocale(java.util.Locale)

Changing the locale directly through the Configuration file will apply the locale change across the entire application. This is probably not what you want.

You will have to explicitly specify the french text to use for that view.

Comment: But i did it on an activity and it worked just fine with only the that textview translated .With this code '
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");

 maintext.setTextLocale(locale);'